# how to redirect to a custom password retrieval page

Tags: customization, bbpress, password

I have a new site and I'm using bbpress beta-3 with it, I've created custom login/register/lost-password pages with the custom templates supplied with bbpress and I can't seem to find the filter/hook/action that "hijacks" the calls to `wp-login.php`. My biggest problem is with the `lost-password` page, I want to redirect with a notice, I can catch the error but I can't catch the `sent password` event.

I'm now using in function.php:

```
function get_password_retrieve_errors(){
    wp_redirect( site_url('lost-password').'?getpass=failed'  );
}

add_filter('lostpassword_redirect', 'get_password_retrieve_errors', 1);
```

and in form-user-lost-pass.php:

```
<?php if ( $_GET['getpass'] == 'failed' ) { ?>
    <div class="bbp-template-notice error">
        <p>Invalid username or e-mail, please try again.</p>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

1. Is there a way to do it?
2. Is there a global $error object which I can always refer to?
3. Is there a global $notifications object I can always refer to?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not completely sure I'm following. Are you trying to create a custom page that allows the user to reset their password? Or redirect them to a custom page when their password fails (is incorrect) when logging in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not sure i really follow you either, BUT what about filtering the wp_lostpassword_url

from [wp-includes/general-template.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/general-template.php)

```
function wp_lostpassword_url( $redirect = '' ) {
            $args = array( 'action' => 'lostpassword' );
            if ( !empty($redirect) ) {
                    $args['redirect_to'] = $redirect;
            }

            $lostpassword_url = add_query_arg( $args, network_site_url('wp-login.php', 'login') );
            return apply_filters( 'lostpassword_url', $lostpassword_url, $redirect );
}
```

looks like it has a filter you could use to point it to your custom URL, and even add your 'getpass' query var

Here's a very basic example:

```
function custom_login_lostpassword_url()
{
    // use a site_url/plugins_url to output the correct URL.
    return "http://.../my-custom-lostpassword-screen.php";
}

add_filter("lostpassword_url", "custom_login_lostpassword_url");
```