# How to redirect users to custom lostpassword page?

Tags: php, functions, redirect, wp-login-form

How to redirect users to custom lostpassword page when they click on the Error: Lost your password?. Because I set a redirect for `wp-login.php` to my custom login page. when a user click on Error: Lost your password? it requests for `wp-login.php` and then automatically redirects to custom login page. I know the function is present on `wp-login.php` file but I don't know what changes shall I make to make this possible. Please help.
I have also renamed wp-login.php.

Comment: Did you see this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22310/how-to-redirect-to-a-custom-password-retrieval-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to adjust the link of the *lost password* page, then there is a designated filter for that:

```
function wpse_133647_custom_lost_password_page() {
    return home_url('/lost-password');
} // function wpse_133647_custom_lost_password_page
add_filter('lostpassword_url', 'wpse_133647_custom_lost_password_page');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply I used this code to redirect `add_action('init','possibly_redirect');

function possibly_redirect(){
 global $pagenow;
 if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow ) {
  wp_redirect('http://mydomain.com/login');
  exit();
 }
}` can please tell me what changes shall I make. I am a newbie to PHP and wordpress. Please help me.

Comment: What you _have_ to do depends on what you _want_ to do. If you want to provide your users a custom login page as well as a custom lost password, your implementation looks different from the one for using a custom login page and the default page for lost password. So what is it that you want to do?

Comment: I want custom login page and custom lostpassword page. Actually I am using theme my login plugin. But after using rename wp-login plugin I have to manually redirect. So I want custom login page and custom lostpassword page. Please help.