# Lost password empty field error redirect to custom login

Tags: customization, login, password

I'm having trouble with a custom login/lost password form on a site I'm building. The site is completely password protected. I have a custom login page and I'm using 'wp_login_failed' and 'authenticate' hooks to manage/redirect failed attempts and empty field when logging in. These work fine and the user stays on my custom login page and gets error messages when they have a failed login attempt.

When I go to the lost password part (this is simply a hidden form on the same page as the login and is displayed with javascript) and click the 'Get New Password' button whithout entering an email or usernam, I get redirected to the default wp-login page.

How would I change this to go to my custom login page instead?

Cheers

Comment: Did you already stumble upon `lostpassword_url` filter as recommended in [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/42198/32946)?